# How to use a variable that is not a constraint or property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

data site:https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/
with below contraints available:

```
merge (t)-[:OF_PLAYER {age:row.playerAge}]->(player)
merge (t)-[:FROM_CLUB]->(source)
merge (t)-[:TO_CLUB]->(destination)
```

I am not sure how to use age to find 'the youngest player transferred from 'Real Madrid' to an English club.'
I tried using query below but not sure how to use age:

```
    MATCH (from:Club)<-[:FROM_CLUB]-(transfer:Transfer)-[:TO_CLUB]->(to:Club),
    (transfer)-[:OF_PLAYER]->(player:age)
    WHERE from.name = "Real Madrid" and to.country="England"
    RETURN player.name
    order by player.age
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix it? If all player nodes have "Player" labels you could also use `(player:Player)`.

```
MATCH (from:Club)<-[:FROM_CLUB]-(transfer:Transfer)-[:TO_CLUB]->(to:Club),
(transfer)-[:OF_PLAYER]->(player)
WHERE from.name = "Real Madrid" AND to.country = "England"
RETURN player.name
ORDER BY player.age
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Regarding `(player:Player)`: If all `OF_PLAYER` end nodes have the `Player` label, then you would still want to use just `(player)` to avoid the expense of a label test of every `player`.

Comment: No it doesn't as age is not imported as the property of player.It is being added as mentioned above as [:OF_PLAYER {age:row.playerAge}]->(player), so not sure how it can be used in query